# jQuery getJson Parseerror Json Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I am trying to perform a very simple getJson() request but no matter what I change I am getting parseerror from jQuery.

I am using ROR 3.01, Mongoid2.0, jQuery 1.5.2

The Controller Sending the json

```
    class SuggestController < ApplicationController

      def states
          states = States.only(:name, :state_id).where(:country_code => params[:country])
          render :json => states.entries
      end

    end
```

Jquery to handle the response.

```
    $("#property_country").change(function(){

        $.getJSON("/suggest/states",{country: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
          options += '<option value="' + j[i].state_id + '">' + j[i].name + '</option>';
        }
        $("select#property_state").html(options);
      });

    });

  $.ajaxSetup({"error":function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {   
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(errorThrown);
        alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
  }});
```

And example of the json response

```
[{"_id":"4d925dbe4aa6936d4f0cdefe","name":"Devon","state_id":1},{"_id":"4d925dbe4aa6936d4f0cdeff","name":"Berwickshire","state_id":2}]
```

I cant seem to find out why im getting parseerror and what it actually means.

Hope you can advise.

Comment: Haven't had any luck reproducing this :/ Does it give you an error if you parse the response manually in the console with $.parseJSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I finally worked it out.

Basically because render => :json already created the objects all I need to do was do a normal get request and then just loop my data.

Hope this helps someone in the future.